# How to remove inserted digit at the end of a metabox in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom metabox in Wordpress but in rendering there is a "1" at the end of my content. I can't figure out how to remove it.

With this call...

```
add_meta_box(2, 'Calendrier de la formation', 'render_formations_calendrier_meta_box', null, 'side');
```

I get this metabox.

[image]

What is this "1" ? And can I remove it ? (it didn't come from my template)

**edit**

```
function render_formations_calendrier_meta_box($post) {
    echo require('templates/partials/admin/formations/calendrier_metabox.php');
}
```

templates/partials/admin/formations/calendrier_metabox.php :

```
<table id="new_date_area">
    <?php $dates = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'next_date') ?>
    <?php foreach($dates as $key => $date) : ?>
        <?php foreach($date as $event) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:10px 0 0 0">
                <input type="text" name="next_date[]" class="datepicker" value="<?= date('d-m-Y', $event) ?>"><span class="dashicons dashicons-trash"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<button id="new_date_button">nouvelle date</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // datepicker
        var format = 'dd-mm-yy'
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat : format
        })

        // new date
        $('#new_date_button').on('click', (click_event) => {
            click_event.preventDefault()
            var row = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="next_date[]" class="datepicker"><span class="dashicons dashicons-trash"></span></td></tr>'
            $('#new_date_area').append(row)
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat : format
            })
        })

        // delete date
        $(document).on('click', '.dashicons-trash', function(e) {
            $(e.target).closest('tr').remove()
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Problem might be in the  function called  render_formations_calendrier_meta_box

Comment: Indeed, please add code of render_formations_calendrier_meta_box() function.

Comment: @NerijusMasikons It only require an html file :


function render_formations_calendrier_meta_box($post) {
    echo require('templates/partials/admin/formations/calendrier_metabox.php');
}

Comment: Then your problem may be in calendrier_metabox.php :)

Comment: I solved it, the "1" was the return of the function require(). I was making echo require() but I only have to do a require without the echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the "1" was the return of the function require(). I was making echo require() but I only have to do a require without the echo.